Why is file download event working for one PDF, but not for another?
I am very new to Google Analytics 4 and currently trying to find out via Google Analytics how many people downloaded a particular PDF. I have Enhanced Measurement set up and everything. However, when I look at the report it provides me with the data on every other PDF except the one I need. The only difference is the code that I can see on our CMS.
On the page where the download works it's
<a href="[~]common/Uploaded files/CBCA/CBCA_2023/Where_the_Lyrebird_Lives.pdf" class="" target="_blank">Download and print this unit</a></span></strong></span></p>
Below is from the page where the download event doesn't show up on the report:
<a href="[~]common/Uploaded files/CBCA/2024 Units/Bowerbird_Blues_AC.pdf" class="" download="">AC Version</a>
As you can see the only difference is that the Bowerbird Blues code is missing the target="_blank" code, does this affect analytics?
Any help would be much appreciated.
I've tried to recreate the report via advice on the Internet but as previously mentioned above it shows up for all pages except the one I need.
